# could not load assemly error when try to load plugins in c#

Tags: c#, plugins, assemblies

I want to create a Plugin architecture so I created the following interface

```
public interface IPlug
{
    string Id { get; }

    string Name { get; }

    byte IsOn { get; }

    bool Execute();
}
```

Now I reference the above interface to another class library project.

```
namespace PlugANameSpace
{
    public class PlugA : IPlug
    {
        private byte _isOn;

        public string Id
        {
            get {return "6666"; }
        }

        public byte IsOn
        {
            get { return _isOn; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return "PlugA"; }
        }

        public PlugA()
        {

            LoadFromRegistry();
        }

        public bool Execute()
        {
             // do some thing that returns true for success or false for error
        }

        private void LoadFromRegistry()
        {
              //register in registry
        }
    }
}
```

The above class library is copied into the main assembly file and stored in a folder "Plugins".  Then I tried to load the plugin with the following code.

```
IPlug plug= Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(file, typeof(IPlug).FullName) as IPlug;
```

file is dll file got from `Directory.GetFiles` method.
When I tried to create instance, it throws error " Could not load type 'IPlug ' from assembly 'PlugA, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.  "

what I am doing wrong.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the name of the type in the PlugA assembly.

```
IPlug plug = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(file, "PlugANameSpace.PlugA") as IPlug;
```

**Edit**: If you want to load a plugin without knowing the name of the type:

```
var assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file);
var assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
var pluginType = assembly.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(t => typeof(IPlug).IsAssignableFrom(t));
IPlug plug = Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType) as IPlug;
```

Comment: " Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation " also it will not be dynamic if I implement PlugB ,PlugC with different namespaces from I plug interface

Comment: @AjitHegde It means the constructor of your plugin class threw an exception. If you want to load the plugin dynamically, you need to examine  the assembly using reflection as Michal Hainc suggested.

Comment: I cleared the code in constructor and its completely empty. Getting "  The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)  "  error at assembly.Load(file). However it gives the correct name if I use AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName method

Comment: If I use Assembly.LoadFrom(file). I will get plugintype as null. I don't understand why it doesn't load interface.

Comment: AssemblyName an = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file);                               Assembly assembly=Assembly.Load(an).   worked.